# MIPS 32-bit unsigned multiplication without using mult or div

Tags: assembly, mips, multiplication, unsigned

I have been working on a program does multiplication of two 32-bit unsigned integers without using the MIPS mult(multu) or div(divu) commands.
I want the output to look just like how the multu function would, as a 64-bit high word/low word combo.
I have been using a model where the multiplier is the right hand side of the product as so:

```
for (i=0; i<32; i++)
{
   if LSB(multiplier)==1
   {
       LH product += multiplicand;
   }
   right shift product-multiplier 1;
}
```

Currently in my code I am unsure if I am taking care of the possible carry-out bit from the 32-bit addition properly.

I am currently getting an output of "0 0" no matter what integer values I choose to operate on.

In my code I am calling the right most bit the LSB(low word), left most the MSB(high word).

My code:

```
.data

    promptStart:    .asciiz "This prrogram does AxB without using mult or div"
           getA:    .asciiz "Please enter the first number(multiplicand): "
           getB:    .asciiz "Please enter the second number(multiplier): "

          space:    .asciiz " "

         result:    .asciiz "The product, using my program is: "
         mipMult:   .asciiz "The product, using MIPs multu is: "

       endLine: .asciiz "\n"

.text

main:
    #"welcome" screen
    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,promptStart     # point $a0 to prompt string
    syscall             # print the prompt


    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,endLine     # point $a0 to prompt string
    syscall             # print the prompt

    #prompt for multiplicand
    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,getA        # point $a0 to prompt string
    syscall             # print the prompt

    #acquire multiplicand
    li  $v0,5           # code for read_int
    syscall             # get an int from user --> returned in $v0
    move    $s0,$v0         # move the resulting int to $s0

    move    $s4,$s0         #copy of multiplicand to use in multu

    #prompt for multiplier
    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,getB        # point $a0 to prompt string
    syscall             # print the prompt

    #acquire multiplier
    li  $v0,5           # code for read_int
    syscall             # get an int from user --> returned in $v0
    move    $s1,$v0         # move the resulting int to $s0

    move    $s5,$s1         #copy of multiplier to use in multu 

    jal MyMult
    j   print

MyMult:

    #$s2 -> lw product, $s1 -> hw multiplier, $s0 -> multiplicand

    beq $s1, $0, done       # if multiplier=0--> mult gives 0
    beq $s0, $0, done

    move    $t0, $0         #initialize 'counter'= 31
    add $t0, $t0, 31

    move    $s2, $0         #initialize product = 0

    loopOut:
        beq $t0, $0, done   #loop check

        andi    $t1, $s1, 1 #Stores LSB(MSB?) of $s1 in $t1
        bne $t1, $0, loopIn #check if LSB is equal to 1
        srl $s1, $s1, 1
        srl $s2, $s2, 1 #right shift product & multiplier

        add $t0, $t0,-1 # counter = counter -1
        j   loopOut

    loopIn:
        addu    $s2, $s2, $s0   #Lw product($s2/$s1)+= multiplicand($s0)
        sltu    $t2, $s2, $s0   #catch carry-out(0 or 1) and stores in $t2      

        srl $s1, $s1, 1
        srl $s2, $s2, 1 #right shift pro-plier..how to save LSB of $s2?

        #add carry-out $t2 to LSB of product $s2
        addu    $s2, $s2, $t0   #Is this right?

        addu    $t0, $t0,-1 # counter = counter -1
        j   loopOut

    done:
        jr $ra

print:
    # print result string
    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,result      # point $a0 to string
    syscall             # print the result string

    # print out the result
    li  $v0,1           # code for print_int
    move    $a0,$s2         # put result in $a0
    syscall             # print out result

    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,space       # point $a0 to string
    syscall             # print the result string

    li  $v0,1           # code for print_int
    move    $a0,$s1         # put result in $a0
    syscall             # print out result


    # print the line feed
    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,endLine     # point $a0 to string
    syscall             # print the linefeed

doMult:
#Do same computation using Mult
    multu   $s4, $s5
    mfhi    $t0
    mflo    $t1

    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,mipMult     # point $a0 to string
    syscall 

    # print out the result
    li  $v0,1           # code for print_int
    move    $a0,$t0         # put high in $a0
    syscall             # print out result

    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,space       # point $a0 to string
    syscall             # print the result string

    # print out the result
    li  $v0,1           # code for print_int
    move    $a0,$t1         # put low in $a0
    syscall             # print out result

    # print the line feed
    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,endLine     # point $a0 to string
    syscall             # print the linefeed

    # All done, thank you!
    li  $v0,10          # code for exit
    syscall             # exit program
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger/simulator to isolate the problem?

Comment: I was using PcSpim to simulate the program...I tried using single stepping but was not really sure how to use it.

Other than that the program itself shows no errors.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, even your algorithm is broken. You should be shifting the multiplicand to the left (for the addition), and the factor to the right (for bit testing). The product should not be shifted. Also, the multiplicand needs to be extended to 64 bits, and you need a 64 bit shift that correctly transfers bits across the word boundary.

```
.data

    promptStart:    .asciiz "This program does AxB without using mult or div"
           getA:    .asciiz "Please enter the first number(multiplicand): "
           getB:    .asciiz "Please enter the second number(multiplier): "

          space:    .asciiz " "

         result:    .asciiz "The product, using my program is: "
         mipMult:   .asciiz "The product, using MIPs multu is: "

       endLine: .asciiz "\n"

.text

main:
    #"welcome" screen
    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,promptStart # point $a0 to prompt string
    syscall             # print the prompt


    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,endLine     # point $a0 to prompt string
    syscall             # print the prompt

    #prompt for multiplicand
    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,getA        # point $a0 to prompt string
    syscall             # print the prompt

    #acquire multiplicand
    li  $v0,5           # code for read_int
    syscall             # get an int from user --> returned in $v0
    move    $s0,$v0     # move the resulting int to $s0
    move    $s5,$s0     # copy of multiplicand to use in multu

    #prompt for multiplier
    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,getB        # point $a0 to prompt string
    syscall             # print the prompt

    #acquire multiplier
    li  $v0,5           # code for read_int
    syscall             # get an int from user --> returned in $v0
    move    $s1,$v0     # move the resulting int to $s0

    move    $s6,$s1     # copy of multiplier to use in multu

    jal MyMult
    j   print

MyMult:
    move $s3, $0        # lw product
    move $s4, $0        # hw product

    beq $s1, $0, done
    beq $s0, $0, done

    move $s2, $0        # extend multiplicand to 64 bits

loop:
    andi $t0, $s0, 1    # LSB(multiplier)
    beq $t0, $0, next   # skip if zero
    addu $s3, $s3, $s1  # lw(product) += lw(multiplicand)
    sltu $t0, $s3, $s1  # catch carry-out(0 or 1)
    addu $s4, $s4, $t0  # hw(product) += carry
    addu $s4, $s4, $s2  # hw(product) += hw(multiplicand)
next:
    # shift multiplicand left
    srl $t0, $s1, 31    # copy bit from lw to hw
    sll $s1, $s1, 1
    sll $s2, $s2, 1
    addu $s2, $s2, $t0

    srl $s0, $s0, 1     # shift multiplier right
    bne $s0, $0, loop

done:
    jr $ra

print:
    # print result string
    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,result      # point $a0 to string
    syscall             # print the result string

    # print out the result
    li  $v0,1           # code for print_int
    move    $a0,$s4     # put result in $a0
    syscall             # print out result

    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,space       # point $a0 to string
    syscall             # print the result string

    li  $v0,1           # code for print_int
    move    $a0,$s3     # put result in $a0
    syscall             # print out result


    # print the line feed
    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,endLine     # point $a0 to string
    syscall             # print the linefeed

doMult:
#Do same computation using Mult
    multu   $s5, $s6
    mfhi    $t0
    mflo    $t1

    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,mipMult     # point $a0 to string
    syscall

    # print out the result
    li  $v0,1           # code for print_int
    move    $a0,$t0         # put high in $a0
    syscall             # print out result

    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,space       # point $a0 to string
    syscall             # print the result string

    # print out the result
    li  $v0,1           # code for print_int
    move    $a0,$t1         # put low in $a0
    syscall             # print out result

    # print the line feed
    li  $v0,4           # code for print_string
    la  $a0,endLine     # point $a0 to string
    syscall             # print the linefeed

    # All done, thank you!
    li  $v0,10          # code for exit
    syscall             # exit program
```

Comment: Thank you that code works! I'm looking at it to try to understand WHY it works. I realize i made a mistake in accidentally calling $s2 the lw product and $s1 the hw multiplier, when I really meant to call $s2 the HW product and $s1 the lw multiplier.

The algorithm I gave is exemplified [here](http://imgur.com/jDIxH2d)

According to that example, it should work, which just means my implementation must have been wrong.

Comment: I see, that's a different algorithm but of course you didn't say that up front :P Anyway, your right shift needs to move the LSB of the high word to the MSB of the low word, just as my left shift does the opposite. Also, the carry needs to be inserted into the MSB, not the LSB as you did.